# sort dropdown items (response from JSON) in vuejs

Tags: vuejs2

Can anyone please suggest me on how to apply sorting to dropdown list in Vue Js
I have used v-select from vuetify

```
`<v-select v-model='coursesList' :options="courses" :enableDropup="true" options-label="name" options-value="id" name='courseName[]'></v-select>`

    mutations:{
     setCourseItems (state,response){
      state.courseItems=response
    }
   }
JSON:
[
  {
    "stock": "available",
    "name": "Higher Engineering maths"
  },
  {
   "stock": "available",
    "name": "Qantum Physics"
  },
  {
    "stock": "available",
    "name": "Biology"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you at least create a [minimal, concrete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? We don't have any idea (1) how your data is structured, (2) what criteria you want the sorting to be carried out on.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can use [the sort method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort an array.

Here your response seems to be a json array, you can call `sort()` on it and give it a custom function for sorting. Example :

```
var myArray = [
  {
    stock: "available",
    name: "Higher Engineering maths"
  },
  {
    stock: "available",
    name: "Qantum Physics"
  },
  {
    stock: "available",
    name: "Biology"
  }
]

myArray.sort(function (item1, item2) => {
    //if the result of this method is negative, item2 is considered "bigger" than item1, and vice versa
    return item1.name.toLowerCase() < item2.name.toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1
})
```

this will sort your array by alphabetical order of the `name` field. Note that `toLowerCase()` is not necessary but it's advised in case you don't control the input and don't want to treat capital letters differently.